# Python XML Parser not Returning XML Elemements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find a way to use Python to parse data from several .xml files that contain part numbers and descriptions for a system my team is working on. Here's what the files look like:

Note: Actual data sanitized for confidentiality reasons.

```
<DOCUMENT>
<config>
<lruname>NFS</lruname>
<swpn>123-A-456-7890</swpn>
<swname>00 NFS ABC DEFGHI XYZ JKL</swname>
<swver>Appid: abc-defghi-xyz  PN: 123-A-456-7890</swver>
</config>
</DOCUMENT>
```

I'd like to pull the  and  datatypes from several of these files into .csv format. My initial thought was to try to parse these data types out into a dictionary using the built in xml.etree library, but for some reason it's not finding the elements:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = '''
<DOCUMENT>
<config>
<lruname>NFS</lruname>
<swpn>123-A-456-7890</swpn>
<swname>00 NFS ABC DEFGHI XYZ JKL</swname>
<swver>Appid: abc-defghi-xyz  PN: 123-A-456-7890</swver>
</config>
</DOCUMENT>
'''

tree = ET.fromstring(data)
PartNo = tree.find('swpn')
Desc = tree.find('swname')

print(PartNo)
```

The above code returns 'None' for some reason, but I would expect it to return the xml element I'm calling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing the `config` level in your XML hierarchy, you could do:

```
part_number = tree.find('config').find('swpn').text
part_desc = tree.find('config').find('swname').text
```

Alternately you can loop through all the elements if you don't want to have to know the structure and use conditionals to find the elements you care about with `tree.iter`.

```
for e in tree.iter():
    if e.tag == 'sqpn':
        part_number = e.text
    if e.tag == 'swname':
        part_desc = e.text
```

Comment: Thanks! This did what I needed it to do!

Answer (score 0):

`ElementTree` and `etree`'s find functionality searchers for direct children.

You can still use it by specifying the entire branch:

```
tree.find('config').find('swpn')
tree.find('config/swpn')
```

If you always want to look for `swpn`, but disregard the structure (e.g. you don't know if it's going to be a child of `config`), you might find it easier to use the `xpath` functionality in `etree` (and not in `ElementTree`):

```
tree = etree.fromstring(data)
tree.xpath('//swpn')
```

In this case, the `//` basically mean that you are looking for elements in `tree`, no matter where they are

If the xml files are small, and you don't care about performance, you can use `minidom` which IMHO is more convenient compared to `lxml`. In this case, your code could be something like this:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
xml = parseString(data)
PartNo = xml.getElementsByTagName('swpn')[0]
Desc = xml.getElementsByTagName('swname')[0]
print(PartNo.firstChild.nodeValue)
```